# Prove $\sin x +\frac{1}{(\sin x)^{\sin x}}<2, \quad x \in(0,\pi/2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

No idea how to prove that. What should I try?
$$\sin x +\frac{1}{(\sin x)^{\sin x}}<2, \quad x \in(0,\pi/2)$$

Comment: Hint; Since $\sin x$ can take any value in $(0,1)$ you really want to show that $u+\frac{1}{u^u}<2$ for any $u\in(0,1)$.

Comment: Analyze the range of  u^u  on interval (0,1)

Comment: You need $\le $ there.

Comment: @somaye in my counterexample I gave you a wrong interval since it's needed to consider $(\pi/2,\pi)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's give it a try though it looks ugly and evil:

Define

$$f(u):=u+u^{-u}-2=u+e^{-u\log u}-2\implies f'(u)=1-u^{-u}\left(\log u+1\right)\implies f'(1)=0 $$

$$f''(u)=u^{-u}\left[\left(\log u+1\right)^2-\frac1u\right]\implies f''(1)=1(1-1)=0$$

$$f'''(u)=-u^{-u}\left((\log u+1)\left[\left(\log u+1\right)^2-\frac1u\right]-2(\log u+1)\frac1u-\frac1{u^2}\right)\implies$$

$$f'''(1)=-1(-2-1)>0$$

and the above means $\,u=1\,$ is the first coordinate of an inflection point for $\,f\,$ and of an extreme point (a minimum) for $\,f'\,$, from which we get that

$$f'(u)\ge 0\;,\;\forall\,u\in(0,1)\implies f(u)\le f(1)= 0\;\;\;\;\text{Q.E.D.}$$

Comment: this is clever.

Comment: @Boy_17, not that much...and I sincerely hope is true. :)

Answer (score 1):

let $$\sin{x}=t$$

use$ AM-GM$,we hve
$$\dfrac{1}{t^t}=\left(\dfrac{1}{t}\right)^t\cdot 1^{1-t}\le t\cdot\dfrac{1}{t}+(1-t)\cdot 1=2-t$$